# "cannot load such file -- chef/rest" when "require 'chef/rest'"

Tags: ruby, rest, chef-infra

Trying to write first program to access chef server via API. Following example program on https://docs.chef.io/api_chef_server.html#examples there supposed to be two lines of code to include `chef::rest` library.

```
require 'chef'
require 'chef/rest'
```

but the code failed with error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from ./rest.rb:4:in `<main>'
        1: from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- chef/rest (LoadError)
```

Chef client version: 14.12.9-1
OS Version: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Any missing steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not share whether you use chef libraries as a part of your cookbooks or as a part of another program that depended on the chef libraries.

if you are at the second case, i.e. outside of a cookbook context, then make sure that you are using Gemfile to manage your chef libraries requirement, then execute your program using bundler.

as you can see, [`Chef::Rest` is deprecated](https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_chef_rest.html)

> The `Chef::REST` class will be removed. `Chef::REST` was deprecated in 12.7.2, and will be removed in Chef 13.
>
> If writing code designed to be run internally to Chef, for example in a cookbook or a knife plugin, transition to using `Chef::ServerAPI`. In most cases this is as simple as creating a `Chef::ServerAPI` instance rather than a `Chef::REST` one.
>
> If writing code to interact with a Chef Server from other code, move to the `chef-api` gem.

so i assume that you are using an old chef version, so for the remedy i will be using chef version 12.6:

```
$ cat Gemfile
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'chef', '12.6.0'

$ cat foo.rb
require 'chef'
require 'chef/rest'

$ bundle install
...
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 46 gems now installed.

$ bundle exec ruby foo.rb
```

Comment: How to use Gemfile to manage chef libraries requirement? Never found any instruction on this.