# Why isn't "knife" honoring my --config option?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I'm setting up a Chef server for the first time. To test, I've created a Docker instance of Chef (https://hub.docker.com/r/cbuisson/chef-server/), and that successfully runs. I can log in, and I can reach the server from my browser.

However, I am trying to use some "knife" commands on this container, and so far haven't been able to.

```
MacBook-Pro:chef user1$ knife node list --config ./.chef/config.rb
ERROR: CONFIGURATION ERROR:127.0.0.1 is an invalid chef_server_url. The URL must start with http://, https://, or chefzero://.
MacBook-Pro:chef user1$ cat ./.chef/config.rb
chef_server_url 'https://127.0.0.1/'
MacBook-Pro:chef user1$
```

Changing the URL in the config file to anything other than 127.0.0.1 still gives this error - as far as I can tell, the --config option doesn't work as described in the documentation, unless I'm seriously misunderstanding something. I haven't been able to find what config file it's reading from, but it's obvious it's not the one I'm specifying with the --config flag.

more troubleshooting:

```
MacBook-Pro:cookbooks$ echo $KNIFE_HOME
/Users/PERSON/.chef/config.rb
MacBook-Pro:cookbooks$ cat $_
chef_server_url 'https://localhost/organizations/COMPANY'
cookbook_email 'person@company.com'

MacBook-Pro:cookbooks $ knife supermarket download hostsfile --config $KNIFE_HOME
ERROR: CONFIGURATION ERROR:127.0.0.1 is an invalid chef_server_url. The URL must start with http://, https://, or chefzero://.
MacBook-Pro:cookbooks$ knife -VV
ERROR: You need to pass a sub-command (e.g., knife SUB-COMMAND)

Usage: knife sub-command (options)
    -s, --server-url URL             Chef Infra Server URL.
[truncated]
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is specific to questions about *writing software*. Questions about using professional sysadmin tools are a better fit for our sister site [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: (Obviously there's overlap -- if you're writing a Chef recipe, that's Ruby code, so it's on-topic here; but this one's a pure usage question).

Comment: Run knife with `-VV` to see which file is being used

Answer (score 1):

you did not specify how do you use chef executable - is it via [chefdk](https://downloads.chef.io/chefdk) or via [chef rubygem](https://rubygems.org/gems/chef).

my favorite is to use the chef rubygem, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55931916/1184717) if the concept is new to you

back to your question, to make sure that your knife configuration file (`./.chef/config.rb`) is being read by chef executable, you can place within the configuration file a small probe ruby code that will output once the file is read. place something like the following into your knife configuration:

```
# .chef/config.rb
puts 'my knife configuration'
```

now execute the knife command once again and check for the `my knife configuration` output. if it isn't there, try repeating it under bundler context as it might solve your pain.

Comment: As a warning: When using chef from gem install you're on your own. Moreover you'll have some troubles with chef15 as it doesn't include the binaries anymore. using `knife -VV` would give which file is read as source config and is ore direct than trying every possible file it try to read..

Comment: Obviously my config file is not being loaded, so I need no further convincing of that..! I can't for the life of me figure out what file it *is* reading from - and why it's ignoring all the rules for searching for the config file in their documentation, and in fact, even the `--config` flag. I installed with `brew` to my recollection... thanks for the tip on the type of install. I checked the usual places - `~/.chef/config.rb`, `$REPO/.chef/config.rb`...

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below to figure which config is being used.

```
knife -VV
```

the above command tells me that the C:/opscode/chef-workstation/bin/knife is being used

I went to that specific location and added puts to check it.
I verified it by executing knife cookbook upload

Now further drilling down to see where is this error comes from.
In the path,

```
C:\opscode\chef-workstation\embedded\lib\ruby\gems\3.0.0\gems\chef-config-17.9.26\lib\chef-config\config.rb
```

Search for the method

```
def self.is_valid_url?(uri)
```

And modified the line
from

```
  url = uri.to_s.strip
```

to

```
  url = 'https://api.chef.io/organizations/org1'.to_s.strip
```

which does the magic.

The issue is with the double-quotes("") for the chef_server_url (uri). Modifying the chef_server_url (uri) to be enclosed in single-quotes (''), makes it work.
Double-quotes ("") is not evaluating and you can verify the same by adding puts statements for url and uri variables in the method.

Now post changing the uri value, knife commands are working perfectly.
And I am able to upload the cookbook as well in the hosted chef.